# Flask: OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, apache, flask, sqlite, server

I am having immense difficulties attempting to get my Flask application's database working. I am following the sample tutorial from Flask and deploying my site on Apache server through an Amazon EC2 instance. I have no difficulties accessing the site, but whenever I try to post to the database I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Checking error.log shows:

```
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713249 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492] [2017-09-13 19:37:47,712] ERROR in app: Exception on /add [POST], referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713291 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713294 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app, referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713296 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]     response = self.full_dispatch_request(), referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713299 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713301 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e), referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713304 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception, referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713306 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713308 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713310 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]     rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713312 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request, referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713314 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args), referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713330 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.py", line 76, in add_entry, referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713333 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492]     [request.form['title'], request.form['text']]), referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
[Wed Sep 13 19:37:47.713334 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27587] [client 209.54.86.83:50492] OperationalError: unable to open database file, referer: http://www.zachflask.tk/
```

I thought this may have something to do with my file permissions, but I `chmod 777 FlaskApp.db` without any outcomes.

```
zld6fd@vanadium:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp$ ls -la
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 5 zld6fd zld6fd 4096 Sep 13 19:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 zld6fd zld6fd 4096 Sep 13 19:37 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 zld6fd zld6fd 3072 Sep 13 19:18 FlaskApp.db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zld6fd zld6fd 3194 Sep 13 19:16 FlaskApp.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zld6fd zld6fd 3943 Sep 13 19:16 FlaskApp.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 zld6fd zld6fd   26 Sep 12 20:39 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 zld6fd zld6fd  177 Sep 12 21:25 __init__.pyc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 zld6fd zld6fd  145 Sep 12 21:33 schema.sql
drwxr-xr-x 5 zld6fd zld6fd 4096 Sep 12 22:14 static
drwxr-xr-x 2 zld6fd zld6fd 4096 Sep 13 00:34 templates
drwxr-xr-x 7 zld6fd zld6fd 4096 Sep 11 23:32 venv
```

My FlaskApp.py file contains the following:

```
# Import statements
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
        render_template, flash

# Application Instance
app = Flask(__name__) # Create the instance
app.config.from_object(__name__) # Load config from this file

# Load default config and override config from an environment variable
app.config.update(dict(
        DATABASE='/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.db',
        SECRET_KEY='development key',
        USERNAME='admin',
        PASSWORD='password'
))
```

And my Apache conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName zachflask.tk
            ServerAdmin zld6fd@mail.missouri.edu

            WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp user=zld6fd group=zld6fd threads=5
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp>
                    WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
                    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog /var/www/FlaskApp/logs/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog /var/www/FlaskApp/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work outside standalone outside apache? Have you turned on all of flasks debuggery/exception reporting?

Comment: @pvg Yes, the application works perfectly running on localhost. I set FLASK_DEBUG=True before doing executing flask run.

Comment: is 'on localhost' the same machine/environment/app?

Comment: @pvg by localhost I mean running from my terminal on my computer. The errors are thrown when I try to run it from an Apache server hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: Right. Don't run it on your terminal, on your computer. Run it on the EC2 instance but without apache, just as a flask standalone app with all the debug crap turned on. Check logs, watch what's spewed on stdout.

Comment: @pvg How would I go about accessing the app through the instance without the Apache server instance? Sorry I'm just a little confused, I am appreciative of the help though

Comment: ssh into the server. run the flask app on the command line with just the built-in dev server (this is covered in the tutorial, I'm reasonably sure).

Comment: @pvg I can go on the server and do `flask run` which results in `* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` but how would I view the application in the browser?

Comment: You don't need no stinking browser. Just hit it up with curl from the same machine.

Comment: @pvg Sorry, I am a bit of a novice at this, but I was able to access the files with curl and everything works as expected on the server as well! What does this mean in terms of it not working over Apache?

Comment: 'access the files' with curl is a little vague, was your flask app responding to your curl request, connecting to the db, etc, etc.

Comment: @pvg I am able to perform a post request through curl `curl -X 'title=First' -F 'text=Entry' http://127.0.01:5000/add` that adds an entry into the database. I can see the entry I add through this curl on the live site.

Comment: Move your db file to a world writeable dir somewhere (other than in your web root, move it to /tmp, or something) and see what happens (adjust the path, of course)

Comment: @pvg that did it! I had been neglecting to check my directory permissions this entire time. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found just as @pvg suggested in the comments. My `FlaskApp.db` had always been set to the correct permissions, but I failed to update the permissions of the directory it was within. I moved the `FlaskApp.db` file into a new `tmp/` folder and ran `sudo chmod 777 tmp`